# TagSoup attributes with namespace prefix

Tags: java, sax, xml-parsing, saxparser

For parsing an xml response using TagSoup I am extending the DefaultHandler, now I have the problem that it ignores an attribute with a qualified name in the method;

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException
```

The element looks as follows;

```
<element xmlns:ns2="http://my.ns.url">{content}</element>
```

when it gets to the startElement method for this element, the atts parameter has no attributes in it. Does anyone know how to fix this without adjusting the xml?

*Edit*
I tried using the `setFeature` method for the feature;

```
http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes
```

But without any result

Comment: Isn't TagSoup parser for HTML? It generates SAX events, but its primary goal is to parse HTML files "from the wild".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by stopping to use TagSoup, and resolved to the standard Android SAXParser. Then I changed feature settings as follows;

```
setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);    
setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes", true);
```